# git: copy remote branch history (the .git/logs folder)

Tags: git

I want to know if there is a way on the git command line to copy the branch history from a remote repo. In other words, I want to copy the `.git/logs` directory from the remote to my `.git/logs` directory -- even if this means overwriting my logs folder.

---

EDIT:

To clarify further, assuming that there is a branch called `foo` on remote called `origin`, I want to be able to type:

```
$ git rev-parse --verify foo@{2}
```

on my computer and have that output the exact same thing as on origin. This requires more than just looking at `git log`.

Furthermore, it is possible for someone to do `git update-ref foo foo^` in order to undo a commit, and that history is only preserved in the `.git/logs` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The history will replicate with clone. All you need to do is checkout the branch and run log.

Example - Assuming your remote repository is `origin` and the branch `foo`.

You can run `git checkout --track -b foo origin/foo` to checkout and track a remote branch

To get the history, ensure you are in the branch `foo` by running `git branch`, now type

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
```

and you can see the history of the branch

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
* 075086d 2012-01-06 | Added for joyent (HEAD, origin/tableUpdate, tableUpdate) [xxx]
* 8352180 2012-01-06 | Added package and loggging [xxx]
* ed9300f 2011-12-26 | Added stylesheet [xxx]
* e8b39fa 2011-12-26 | Increased templating, renamed div to meaningful names [xxx]
```

If I switch to master it will be different, running `git checkout master` and `git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short`, I get

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --graph --date=short
* 6402a2e 2012-01-08 | Added README (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) [xxx]
* 292c57a 2012-01-08 | Removed port, this is autodetected [xxx]
* e0ef362 2012-01-08 | Changed port to 8080 and document lookup is dynamic [xxx]
```

Finally, to prevent your fingers mangling or falling off when typing that long log command. You can create a shortcut, create in your home directory (assuming Unix) `~/.gitconfig` and add the line

```
[alias]
    hist = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short
```

You can then just run `git hist`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not quite do everything I'm hoping for, but it does get the information across in most normal situations. See my edit to my question.